# Actived Route is undefined in service's constructor

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

There is a service `trackUrlService` which is imported to `CoreModule`

```
export class TrackUrlService implements OnDestroy {

    ...

    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        ...

        this.subs.add(
            this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
                console.log(params.workflowId); // output: undefined
                ...
            })
        );
    }
...
```

There is a component `DummyComponent`

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.subs.add(
            this.trackUrl.currWorkflowId.subscribe(currWorkflowId => {
                console.log(currWorkflowId); // output: undefined
            }),
            ...
            /* this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                console.log(params.workflowId) // output: 391 (correct)
            }), */
         ...
```

**QUESTION:**

Why calling `this.route.params` from service's constructor outputs `undefined`?

But calling `this.route.params` from the components' `ngOnInit()` works and outputs a correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ActivatedRoute` docs: "Provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet", i.e `ActivatedRoute` `params` visible just inside route component.